# Error 'Multiple Directive Resource Contention' when creating custom directive and using UI-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that has as input the rating and which plots stars in the DOM based on this input.

However, when I try the following:

```
.directive('stars', function (Utils) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment  
        transclude: true,
        template: "{{starsObj}}",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

           scope.starsObj = Utils.returnStars(attrs.rating)

        } 
    }

})
```

where `Utils.returnStars(attrs.rating)` returns an array (which I would like to use later).

... I get the following error:

> Multiple Directive Resource Contention
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=rating&p1=%20(module:%20ui.bootstrap.rating)&p2=stars&p3=%20(module:%20noodl.controllers-product)&p4=template&p5=%3Cspan%20ng-mouseleave%3D%22reset()%22%20rating%3D%225%22%3E

Removing ui-bootstrap from my projects resolves the issue, but I do need ui-bootstrap in the end.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add 'scope.' prefix to your variables from directive scope, so you should change your `template` attribute of the directive to this:

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment  
    transclude: true,
    template: "{{starsObj}}", //You don't need 'scope.' prefix.
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

       scope.starsObj = Utils.returnStars(attrs.rating)

    } 
}
```

[Demo on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/npzd4vCSC2AEYkMj1txV?p=preview)

**UPD:** But I see that your error from the console is related to `ui-bootstrap`. Can you provide code more code, where you use it?

**UPD2:** The issue here is that `ui.bootstrap` has his own [rating](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/rating) directive. So, to solve this problem you can just rename your `rating` attribute of `stars` directive to something else. I updated my plunker.

Comment: ah yeah, indeed removing ui-bootstrap resolves it... so the problem is actually something else. I only use ui-bootstrap for a carousel..

Comment: Are there any errors or something? Or your directive just doesn't display needed information?

Comment: I get the Multiple Directive Resource Contention error? Really weird